# Adoquery1 missing sql property - Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, tadoquery, adoconnection

I'm trying to add some data in an access database. But I'm having trouble because this returning the error:

```
ADOQuery1 missing sql property
```

Realized several modifications to the code and so far nothing has worked .

What am I doing wrong ?

```
try
    ADOConnection1.Connected := true;
    ADOQuery1.Active := true;
    try
        ///
        AdoQuery1.SQL.Clear;
        ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO IP (tit_ip, url_ip, im_ip, des_ip) VALUES ( :a, :b, :c, :d )');
        AdoQuery1.parameters.parambyname('a').value := 'sd';
        AdoQuery1.parameters.parambyname('b').value := 'sdsd';
        AdoQuery1.parameters.parambyname('c').value := 'sd';
        AdoQuery1.parameters.parambyname('d').value := 'df';
        AdoQuery1.ExecSQL;
        AdoQuery1.close;
    finally
        ADOQuery1.Active := false;
        ADOConnection1.Connected := false;
    end;
except
    showmessage('Erro');
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger should have shown you the line that failed. Remove

```
 ADOQuery1.Active := true;
```

That is the same as opening a query, but you do that before you set the SQL. If you do insert, delete or update you should really use a `TADOCommand` instead of a `TADOQuery`, but a `TADOQuery` will work.

Comment: You were opening the query without SQL when you called activate

Comment: Thanks.       ATT  ABCD